# Code Push and updates to NPM modules

Tags: cordova, code-push, visual-studio-app-center

I have a Cordova app that leverages [Code Push](https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/) to handle small/medium changes without requiring users to go back to the app store.  I know that new native functionality cannot be pushed via code push, as that typically requires new native permissions etc.  For Cordova this would be any plugin changes.

However, I'm not certain if NPM module adjustments would get picked up via code push updates?  Is anyone able to shed light on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We definitely send out NPM module changes. When you do a CodePush release your entire JS bundle is sent to our backend where we produce diff's to send out to users. Any changes at all with be patched and applied on the devices including packages. Without them we wouldn't be able to guarantee any update would be able to run successfully.

Comment: Code push does not work for me in node_modules, perhaps it is because of typescript ?

Comment: @Patrick Nikoletich Package.json npm module which I have updated with no native changes will also go in the code push update ? or only application javascript code ?

Answer (score 0):

I found an NPM module that exposed a convenient version indicator.  This allowed me to confirm that NPM adjustments **are**, indeed, pushed out with Code Push.

FYI - I am using Ionic which leverages angular 2+ and webpack.  I'm no expert here, but it seems that webpack is bundling and minifying the NPM modules into a `vendor.js` file.  This file (along with the other bundled files) are included in the code push, which is why the NPM module updates are included.